# Helm install NGINX ingress controller tries to look up AKS DNS with wrong region

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

Tried to follow this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli to setup ingress controller in AKS with its region **EastUS2**. When I tried to run the command as given in the doc:

> helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx 
> --version 4.1.3 
> --namespace ingress-basic 
> --create-namespace 
> --set controller.replicaCount=2 
> --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes.io/os"=linux 
> --set controller.image.registry=$ACR_URL 
> --set controller.image.image=$CONTROLLER_IMAGE 
> --set controller.image.tag=$CONTROLLER_TAG 
> --set controller.image.digest="" 
> --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes.io/os"=linux 
> --set controller.service.annotations."service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz 
> --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.registry=$ACR_URL 
> --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.image=$PATCH_IMAGE 
> --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.tag=$PATCH_TAG 
> --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.digest="" 
> --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes.io/os"=linux 
> --set defaultBackend.image.registry=$ACR_URL 
> --set defaultBackend.image.image=$DEFAULTBACKEND_IMAGE 
> --set defaultBackend.image.tag=$DEFAULTBACKEND_TAG 
> --set defaultBackend.image.digest="" 
> -f internal-ingress.yaml

It gives the error:
`INSTALLATION FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://testaks-dns-38ca4dd8.hcp.centralus.azmk8s.io:443/version": dial tcp: lookup testaks-dns-38ca4dd8.hcp.centralus.azmk8s.io on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host`

The actual API Server address is testaks-dns-04129ffe.hcp.**eastus2**.azmk8s.io. For some reason its trying to lookup 'centralus' in the domain name.

Could not find where the region centralus is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the kubeconfig file for the `helm` command with `--kubeconfig config-file`,

or your should replace the default one located in `~/.kube/config`.

The correct kubeconfig file should contain the right K8s cluster server address: **testaks-dns-04129ffe.hcp.eastus2.azmk8s.io**, not the wrong one.

Comment: That got resolved though I am now facing a ssl/cert issue now
`Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://testaks-learnaksrg-232406-c365cb37.hcp.eastus2.azmk8s.io/version": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca")`

Comment: @ElsabathPuthumana You may need to renew the whole kubeconfig file, not just cluster server address.

Comment: can you point me some links where this is shown how

Comment: @ElsabathPuthumana refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/control-kubeconfig-access#available-cluster-roles-permissions